# How do I incement date by 6 months in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I want to increment months by 6 in Java, currently I am using below code. But it is always printing first month. Can you kindly let me know what I am doing mistake here? I am beginner in Java.

This is my output :

Current date : 11-1-2013

date after 6 months : 11-7-2013

Expected output:

Current date: 11-05-2013

date after 6 months : 11-11-2013

```
        String dt = "11-05-2013";
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy"); 
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = (Date)formatter.parse(dt);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();    
        now.setTime(date);



        System.out.println("Current date : " + now.get(Calendar.DATE)+ "-" +(now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-"
             + now.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        now.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);

        System.out.println("date after 6 months : " +  now.get(Calendar.DATE)+"-" + (now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-"
             + now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Comment: @matsev Not a duplicate, just a parse error :)

Comment: also, after fixing the formatter, you can use it to output your date as well: `formatter.format(now.getTime())` instead of getting individual fields

Comment: Could someone please explain why is there a `+ 1` to `Calendar.MONTH`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with capital M:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: +1 Exactly what I think is the error too, you can say that currently his month is evaluated as minutes.

Comment: Proper explanation: *mm is for minute parsing, MM is for month parsing*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thank you to verify that my brain is working properly :)

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie it happens to me when I'm still wake up lately at nights (like right now =\\).

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you would have solved the issue. Any way as an alternate answer, I would suggest using the Joda API. Please check on to the documenataions. http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html?org/joda/time/DateTime.html. Just use the method plusMonths(int months) to add the required number of months to the given datetime.

Joda provides additional functions like date difference and many more. It suits an average user perfectly. Read more on http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html

Comment: While this is completely true, I find it a bit overkill to use Joda API just to solve this problem. And yes, I prefer using Joda API against Java `Date` and `Calendar` classes.

Comment: Well said @LuiggiMendoza. Just mentioned Joda as an alternate to the normal Date class. It solves lot of complications of java date problems.